# cite figure in other figure caption in markdown to pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

Using R markdown with PDF output, I want to cite a figure into another figure caption. I also want to cite a BibTex reference in the caption. Any ideas? Here's an example of code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "today"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    number_sections: no
linestretch: 1.5
bibliography: input/Library.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

```{r}
df <- mtcars

library(ggplot2)
```

```{r, fig.cap="some stuff"}
ggplot(df, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()

```



```{r, fig.cap="some more stuff. here I'd like to cite figure 1. I would also like a BibTex citation"}
ggplot(df, aes(cyl, hp)) + geom_point()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

In my experience cross-referencing works better when one uses `bookdown::pdf_document2` or `bookdown::html_document2`. Note that it makes sense to name the chunk that produces the figure since that name is used in the label used for referencing:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "today"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    number_sections: no
  bookdown::html_document2:
    default
linestretch: 1.5
bibliography: packages.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
knitr::write_bib(c(.packages()), 'packages.bib')
```

```{r}
df <- mtcars

library(ggplot2)
```

```{r stuff, fig.cap="some stuff"}
ggplot(df, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()

```



```{r, fig.cap="some more stuff. here I'd like to cite figure \\@ref(fig:stuff). I would also like a BibTex citation [@R-base]"}
ggplot(df, aes(cyl, hp)) + geom_point()
```
````

For the BibTeX reference I am using an automatically created one, but the adaption to your case should be obvious.

Comment: That doesn't generalize to `html_output`.  It would be nice to have a solution that does.

Comment: @FrankHarrell For HTML output you can use `bookdown::html_document2`. See updated answer.